# Auto-Update Java Client/Server Model

Tags: java, server, client-server

I'm working with a chat app in Java that uses an MVC Client-Server model. For the conversations screen, I currently have an "Update" button that refreshes the chat every time, so if someone i'm talking to posted a message it won't be displayed until after i hit "update"

Wondering if there's another way to do that? I know of the blinker method that re-updates every few seconds, but that seems like bad style. 
Thanks!

Comment: AOL IM had real time automatic updates 30 years ago. So yes, it can be done

Answer (score 0):

You can use websocket for that. If you are using spring boot, have a look at [this guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/).